# Is something broken with the "top tags"?

Tags: bug, tags, profile-page

When I take a look at my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem?tab=profile) on Stack Overflow, I see the following list of "top tags":

[image]

However when I take a look at the list of tags (or the activity tab), it looks like:

[image]

Notice that [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) here has a score of 179 whereas [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) only has a score of 154, so in the list of top tags, [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) should be placed as the 5th or 6th element, not [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list). Perhaps this bug only occurs if tags have exactly the same score? This problem already persists for a few days so simply a synchronization error does not seem to be a plausible explanation.

Is something broken with the tag system?

Comment: AFAIK, rarer ones have priority.

Comment: But in that case wouldn't it make more sense to show "top ??%"? Since this is not shown at all, it is counterintuitive.

Comment: I have such oddities as well. (Profile: Postgresql 20/17, Swing 16/13, Hibernate 15/10; ActivityTags: Posgres, Tomcat 19/5, Swing, Hibernate; So Tomcat should show, but isn't and Hibernate should not show but does)

Comment: @Braiam If it were rarity, shouldn't it then show prolog in favor of list at Willems Profile?

Comment: -1 for lack of freehand red circles

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: sorry, last years I'm more into vector graphics :) Furthermore what is the use of dv since there is no longer a reputation system on so.

Comment: At least you could have created some perfectly antialiased ellipses centered around the problem areas.

Comment: @MrLister: If I find some time, I will try to update the images :)

Comment: Would post number have something to do with it? List has more than Algorithm - maybe a balance between score and posts

Comment: Fixed the broken images.

Comment: @ken2k: unfortunately you swapped the two images :p. Fixed the fixed broken images.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I had one job... sorry :/

Comment: I saw this question yesterday and didn't quite understand so I moved on, coming back to freehand red circles it actually makes sense now, interesting.

Comment: @Carrosive Your comment is confusing.  It lacks something.  Maybe some circles?

Comment: Well things are getting worse: [algorithm] now should be placed before [regex].

Comment: I fixed the problem by investing in tags other than [algorithm] so now both lists are in sync again.